# Wrong waveform (spectrogramm) using Telegram API sendVoice method

Tags: telegram, ogg, aiogram, opus

I tried to send a voice message via the Telegram API, but I encountered a problem that the spectrogram was not displayed correctly.

The Telegram API documentation says:

> Use this method to send audio files, if you want Telegram clients to display the file as a playable voice message. For this to work, your audio must be in an .OGG file encoded with OPUS.

The problem is that the spectrogram is displayed, but does not reflect what is happening in the audio recording, that is, where there is complete silence in the audio recording, the spectrogram shows that there is sound (audacity shows the spectrogram for the same file correctly)

The way I convert the file:

```
audio_segment = AudioSegment.from_file(io.BytesIO(audio_data), format="wav")
ogg_data_stream = io.BytesIO()
audio_segment.export(ogg_data_stream, format="ogg", codec="opus", bitrate="48k", parameters=['-strict', '-2'])
ogg_data = ogg_data_stream.getvalue()
```

The way I send message:

```
audio_stream = BytesIO(ogg_data)
audio_stream.name = "voice.ogg"
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{Config.BOT_TOKEN}/sendVoice"
files = {'voice': ('voice.ogg', audio_stream, 'audio/ogg')}
data = {'chat_id': message.chat.id, 'duration': int(0.5 * len(audio_data) / 22050)}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

In this case spectogramm looks like:

[image]

but the problem is that in the middle of this recording there is a big gap with silence (which can be seen in audacity, but not in telegram)

If I save the file and view information about it, I see the following:

```
(.venv) sudden@MacBook-Pro project % mediainfo bot/voice.ogg                                                                                                         
General
Complete name                            : bot/voice.ogg
Format                                   : Ogg
File size                                : 3.85 KiB
Duration                                 : 618 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 51.0 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavc60.31.102 opus

Audio
ID                                       : 2244360202 (0x85C6380A)
Format                                   : Opus
Duration                                 : 618 ms
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : M
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Writing library                          : Lavf60.16.100


(.venv) sudden@MacBook-Pro project % file --mime-type -b bot/voice.ogg                                                                                               
audio/ogg
```

Tried various conversion options (opus, libopus), via ffmpeg subprocess,
I tried sending via aiogram or directly via telegram API, the result is the same.

Comment: Since you said the spectrogram is displaying OK in Audacity, looks like the problem must be in the way you send the message to Telegram, is this 'duration': int(0.5 * len(audio_data) / 22050) correct?

Comment: its optional parameter, if i remove it, nothing change

Comment: Maybe you can try what happens if you send the voice message directly in telegram chat, does it display the spectrogram correctly?

Comment: if I save the file and drag n drop it to Telegram, the spectrogram is still incorrect

Comment: At this point i think there must be something wrong within the telegram application itself, because if audacity displays it correctly the file must be OK?

Comment: Also your API call must be OK if you get the same results as sending the file directly in telegram app